# Can I improve performance of a build server by switching from EBS to EFS storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

I am wondering if I can obtain serious improvements in performance by reconfiguring our Jenkins build server to use EFS (AWS NFS implementation) instead of EBS disks.

While EFS is about 3x more expensive per gigabyte the real cost is probably going to be only around 2x more expensive because on EFS you pay only for used space, as opposed to EBS where you pay all of it.

Also EFS has another very important advantage: it does scale without having to take anything down for upgrade. Resizing EBS disk is a time consuming operations that involves downtimes.

This question is not about the cost, is more about performance as if I can improve the build speed even by 20% the storage cost would clearly be overcomed (not to mention the advantage of needing less maintenance later).

Comment: EBS has lower latency. Building usually needs many small source files, so ill bet on EBS. Why dont you try it?

Comment: @BretzL Unless I get some data from someone that already did a test, I will do it and contribute back all the results. In addition to this I am also evaluating the same approach for storing docker images that are build by jenkins. Still, hosting docker data on NFS different enough to be addressed separately.

Comment: "Amazon EBS can deliver performance for workloads that require the lowest-latency access to data from a single EC2 instance." I don't think you'll see an improvement in performance with EFS over EBS.

Answer (score 11):

From my direct experience, this is a very bad idea for a Jenkins server. We thought to save ourselves the administrative and automation overheads of creating, expanding, and otherwise managing EBS volumes, so we put our Jenkins home on an EFS mount.

The trouble is that Jenkins builds often involve lots of tiny files (for example, Javascript npm modules), which are the worst-case scenario for EFS, and indeed any NFS implementation. File-based storage requires server round-trips for each file access. In our specific case, cleaning out workspaces of even small projects can take several minutes on a Jenkins server with its home directory on EFS.

Save yourself the trouble, learn from our mistakes; we are going to undo this choice. Your Jenkins server will almost certainly be much slower than one based on EBS.

Comment: I wouldn't describe the issue better :)

Comment: I wish we had searched for this before we did the same mistake. A 15 minute job now takes over an hour. We'll undo this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my intermediary results of my attempt of using AWS EFS for storing Jenkins home directory (which includes the workspaces).

My mistake was that I missed this well hidden page about [EFS performance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html#bursting) which I would summarize that unless you want to store huge amount of data on EFS, it can burst only for 0.5% of the day.... where burst is what we would all expect as the normal performance.

It seems the EFS is not only damn slow, it is extremely slow, so slow that I failed to do an rsync of only 8GB of data from the local EBS volume to the EFS one.

```
root@hostname:/efs# time rsync -ah --info=progress2 /jenkins/ /efs
        816.72M   6%  609.02kB/s    0:21:49 (xfr#12490, ir-chk=1009/273305)
          2.71G  18%  871.55kB/s    0:50:40 (xfr#42955, ir-chk=1070/306870)
```

The average speed was around 1.5mB/s which is ridiculous.

Due to this I decided not even to test running a jenkins build job jenkins on it.

I tried to see if this was caused by AWS that was limiting my speed but the monitoring on EFS does not point that's the case. I think that's the **expected performance that you may get if you have to handle lots of small files**. Have a look at the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if we change performance mode to Max IO and provisioned IOPS to about 2 or 3 mbps is dramatically better? It only costs like $20 per month or less